# Transformar ciclo em função de ordem superior

Tags: python

Boa tarde, tenho esta função contendo um ciclo:

```
def ciclo(x,y):
    lista = []
    for i in x:
        if i[0]==y:
            lista.append(i[3])
    return sorted(lista)
```

E eu queria transformá-la numa linha de código, usando a função map do python.

Já tenho isto: `sorted(map(lambda i: i[3], x))`

Mas isto contém só o ciclo, o `if i[0]==y` eu não sei como fazer para metê-lo ai dentro da função map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia usar [expressões condicionais](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (meio que um ternário exótico) e retornar `None` caso `[0]` seja diferente de `y` e depois aplicar um `filter` para remover os Nones:

```
def higherOrderCycle(x, y):
    return sorted(
        filter(
            lambda v: v != None, 
            map(lambda v: v[3] if v[0] == y else None, x)
        )
    )
```

Veja que caso você esteja esperando `None` em `v[3]` seria necessário adaptar essa função. Também embora a implementação com funções de ordem superior seja muito bonita e dentro do paradigma funcional ela é bem mais obscura que a que você postou, então fora o aprendizado não vejo motivo para usá-la no lugar da outra.

Comment: sim tem razão, eu pensei que conseguia por o código todo numa só linha, mas vejo que não... Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Em Python isso ai é uma linha:

```
sorted(i[3] for i in x if i[0] == y)
```

Esqueça o uso de "map"  em geral ele é mais complicado do que os "generator expressions" e "list comprehensions" que temos embutidos na linguagem - 
esses nomes chiques são para uso do comando "for" em uma expressão *inline*, como fiz acima -  e permitem, sem o uso das funções "map", "filter", ou da palavra chave "lambda"  o mapeamento e filtragem de qualquer conjunto de dados:

Basicamente, você escreve `"<expressão>  for item in <iterador> if <expressão-de-filtro>"` em qualquer lugar onde a linguagem espere um iterador - ele vai te dar todos os items do iterador, e para cada um, vai processar a `< Expressão>` se a `expressão-de-filtro` for verdadeira. 
Ou seja, a expressão inicial faz o papel do "map", e a expressão depois do "if" faz o papel do "filter".

Se quiser o resultado final numa lista, ponha essa sintaxe entre colchetes.
(`[<expressão>  for item in <iterador> if <expressão-de-filtro>]`)  - no caso, como você quer os resultados ordenados, em vez disso, passei o iterador para uma chamada a `sorted` que retorna um objeto `list`  já ordenado.

A expressão que dei como resposta acima seria o equivalente a:

```
map((lambda i: i[3]), filter((lambda i: i[0] == y), x) )
```

(ou seja, o iterador retornado pela chamada ao  `filter` é o parâmetro de sequência para a chamada ao `map` - fica bem mais difícil de ler)

(tambem note que é melhor proteger os lambdas com parênteses para evitar ambiguidade, para leitores humanos, se a "," indica o fim do lambda, ou indica que o lambda vai retornar uma tupla, em vez de um único resultado)